# problem in TCPDF output in webview android with php

Tags: php, android

I got an apk output from my software as a web view. Everything works fine, but when I want to get a pdf output with this function, it gives me a blank pdf.

normally everything is fine and the pdf output is completely healthy and there is no problem

Has anyone ever had this problem to guide me

```
function pdfWorker($record)
{
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, array(400, 500), PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $lg = array();
    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
    $lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
    $lg['w_page'] = 'page';
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
    $pdf->SetFont('xyekan', '', 12);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $tbl_header = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border=".5" style="border-color:gray;">
                <tr style="background-color:#686D76;color:white;">
                <td width="10%">درخواست کننده</td>
                <td width="10%">تاریخ اعلام نیاز</td>
                <td width="10%">تعداد کارگران</td>
                <td width="10%">موقعیت کاری</td>
                <td width="40%">شرح کار</td>
                <td width="10%">تاریخ نیاز</td>
                <td width="10%">تاییده مدیریت</td>
                </tr>';
    $tbl_footer = '</table>';
    $tbl = '';
    foreach ($record as $row) {  
        $userSender = $row['fullname'];
        $dateRequest = $row['dateRequest'];
        $workerNumber = $row['workerNumber'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $dateNeed = $row['dateNeed'];
        if ($row['confirm'] != null) {
            $confirm = $row['confirm'];
        } else {
            $confirm = "مورد تایید";
        }
        $tbl .=
            '
            <tr>
            <td>' . $userSender . '</td>
            <td>' . $dateRequest . '</td>
            <td>' . $workerNumber . '</td>
            <td>' . $location . '</td>
            <td>' . $description . '</td>
            <td>' . $dateNeed . '</td>
            <td>' . $confirm . '</td>
            </tr>
';
    }
    $fileName = generateHash(5);
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, true, false);
    $pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you are having this problem with an android app calling this function (thru a webview) ? If this is the case, do you have the same problem when it is rendered thru a web browser in say a PC ??

Comment: @KenLee yes problem with an android app calling this function (thru a webview).

Comment: @KenLee No, I do not have a problem with the desktop browser or even the phone browser, only in webview

Comment: I see, please see my suggested solution

Answer (score 0):

For android app (and / or iOS app) using webview to display a pdf, please

1. save the pdf into your server (instead of forcing a download)

So , change this line

```
 $pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
```

to

```
 $pdf->Output($fileName, 'F');
```

2. Then, please use the following code to trigger a pdf viewer
   (make sure url=xxxxxx.pdf is valid, for example, change to url=http://www.yourdomainname.com/pdffilename.pdf) to view the generated pdf.

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=xxxxxx.pdf" with="100%" height="375"></embed>
```